# Differing outputs when compressing string using LZMA-JS in javascript vs org.tukaani.xz in java

Tags: javascript, java, compression, lzma

Apologies for the novice query, I've inherited some infrastructure and still wrapping my head around the unusual structure they've got setup here.

I have the below in JS and need to replicate the compression in Java but struggling to get the same result or even same structure of output but cant understand why.

I've even tested using echo/unix commands and that seems to match java output structure.
(ie piping echo into "| xz -z -9 -c | base64" )
It's almost definitely due to a gap in my understanding of what the javascript is doing here but can someone point me in the right direction/explain why the JS compression is differing so much from java/unix commands

Backing classes:

```
export default class LZMA {
  constructor() {
    this.LZMAinternal = new LZMA_WORKER();
  }

  async compress(input, mode = 9) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
      this.LZMAinternal.compress(input, mode, (result, error) => {
        if (result) return res(result);
        rej(error);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Main function calls (I want to replicate what is returned here in java)

```
const compressedBuffer = lzmaInstance.LZMAinternal.compress(string);
return Buffer.from(compressedBuffer).toString('base64');
```

I was attempting to recreate using org.tukaani.xz java library. However output structures look extremely different. Examples below of outputs (base64 encoded after the compression, I've confirmed it's not that base64 encoding that's the issue):

The input stringified json Object:

```
{"current":1,"resultsPerPage":30,"filters":[],"sortDirection":"desc","sortField":"releasedate","searchTerm":""}
```

Java/unix output:

```
/Td6WFoAAATm1rRGAgAhARwAAAAQz1jM4AB5AGZdAD2IiGeUEJx+YNDVSn+g13PJsqImqAnM48D6eQaUMbHDe9+RgNqpzYzom2xwbUPQBqoYmPFSkDFxpTBKCC7IdKwpZ71HTS8zvje4WaeXgtnzpZvdSH5L/KLoKGZAhv/wcTqptSaMKAAAABuSpdXZjxZ9AAGCAXoAAABGCM+pscRn+wIAAAAABFla
```

JS output:

```
XQAAgABvAAAAAAAAAAA9iIhnlBCcfmDQ1UrSxfZBo6le37FCAa6Ceb1FGA4qtkbpQAzUfCetkuCC1O3BFgLm8JItARFdH8B8EIEBdZ0dOELKreRlTUht/AvTBOcU0sdtiYF3dEspUYEHFcbYS79m27z//+aLwAA=
```

Comment: There could be a difference in buffer sizes or configurations. What happens when you decompress each output with both implementations? It is not important if the outputs are different as long as they can be decompressed interchangeably.

Comment: There is no assurance, nor any need, that those outputs be the same. The assurance is that they both then decompress to the same thing. Do they? If so, then there is no problem.

Comment: Do they decompress to the exact same binary? Does the java/unix version (that is longer) have additional meta data? Are you using the exact same parameters to compress?

Comment: Note that in your example above, you are not calling the async function that uses `mode = 9`, but you are calling `LZMAinternal.compress` directly, with default parameters.

Comment: @some I've tried tweaking the compress level in java none of them look remotely like js output and when i pass to backed js server in url the java ones dont work.
i dont think there's anything addition in java/unix the unix commaand im using is:

echo -n '{"current":1,"resultsPerPage":30,"filters":[],"sortDirection":"desc","sortField":"releasedate","searchTerm":""}' | lzma -c -z -9 | base64

Comment: When I run `echo -n '{"current":1,"resultsPerPage":30,"filters":[],"sortDirection":"desc","sortField":"releasedate","searchTerm":""}' | lzma -c -z -9 | base64` I get `XQAAAAT//////////wA9iIhnlBCcfmDQ1UrSxfZBo6le37FCAa6Ceb1FGA4qtkbpQAzUfCetkuCC1O3BFgLm8JItARFdH8B8EIEBdZ0dOELKreRlTUht/AvTBOcU0sdtiYF3dEspUYEHFcbYS79m27z//+aLwAA=` which decompresses to exactly the same string. I can't decompress the output you got from java with the unix version of lmza. Something is wrong with your generation of the string.

Comment: By the way, I fixed the indentation of the code in your question. It was unreadable, and you missed the closing brace.